# How can i get the cell value which is highlighted in some color

Tags: excel, vba

Can anyone help me out to get the cell value of which is highlighted with some color.
Below is the code where i am able to get the address. but when i change to .cell.Value it is poping up object reference error.

````
Sub ColorCellValue()
    Dim rCell As Range
    Dim lColor As Long
    Dim rColored As Range
    Dim rs As String
    Dim rng1 As Range
    'Dim EmailRange As Range
    'Select the color by name (8 possible)
    'vbBlack, vbBlue, vbGreen, vbCyan,
    'vbRed, vbMagenta, vbYellow, vbWhite
    'lColor = vbGreen

    'If you prefer, you can use the RGB function
    'to specify a color
    lColor = RGB(0, 255, 0)
    Set rng1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B:B")
    Set rColored = Nothing
    For Each rCell In rng1
        If rCell.Interior.color = RGB(0, 255, 0) Then
            If rColored Is Nothing Then
                Set rColored = rCell
            Else
                Set rColored = Union(rColored, rCell)
            End If
        End If
    Next
    If rColored Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "No cells match the color"
    Else
        rColored.Select
        MsgBox "Selected cells match the color:" & _
            vbCrLf & rColored.Address
    End If
    Set rCell = Nothing
    Set rColored = Nothing
End Sub

```
````

Comment: What is the revised code you are trying?

Comment: Not sure what you're doing but you can't access the value of multiple cells in one go.

Comment: Hello SJR , any other possible way to get the cell value?

Comment: Your code works for me but not with `Set rng1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B:B")` That's 1.4 million cells to loop through with `For ... Each`. It works if you limit the range. I set the range as B2:B50 and got the MsgBox. I then looped through the cells in rColored and printed the value of each cell of it.

Comment: Hi , can you please suggest me the piece of code how to get the value of each cell?

Comment: @Variatus , i tried looping through rcolored as seen above but when i am trying for cell.value it gives me object reference error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please find below working and tested code. It needs some green - RGB(0,255,0) = 65280 - cells in column B and some entries in the green cells. Note that it omits cell B1 from the search.

```
Sub ColorCellValue()

    Dim Rng1 As Range
    Dim rCell As Range
    Dim lColor As Long
    Dim rColored As Range
    Dim Txt As String
    Dim i As Long

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        Set Rng1 = .Range(.Cells(2, 2), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp))
    End With

    lColor = 65280
    'If you prefer, you can use the RGB function to specify a color
    lColor = RGB(0, 255, 0)

    For Each rCell In Rng1
        If rCell.Interior.Color = lColor Then
            If rColored Is Nothing Then
                Set rColored = rCell
            Else
                Set rColored = Union(rColored, rCell)
            End If
        End If
    Next

    If rColored Is Nothing Then
        Txt = "No cells match the color."
    Else
        Txt = "Selected cells match the color:"
        For i = 1 To rColored.Areas.Count
            Txt = Txt & vbCr & rColored.Areas(i).Address _
                      & " = " & rColored.Areas(i).Cells(1).Value
        Next i
        rColored.Select
    End If
        MsgBox Txt, vbInformation, "Search report"
End Sub
```

You can Debug.Print `rColored.Address` but you won't be able to Debug.Print `rColored.Value` if the range consists of more than one cell. Since the range isn't contiguous you may not be able to loop through it looking at each cell. You may have to loop through all its `Areas` and then `For Each Cell in Area(i)`. The code - it's your code in essence which I just sorted a little - is OK. It produces the range you intend it to concatenate. The problem, therefore, must be with the way you are trying to access the range. My code does that. So you can copy my methods to use for your own plans.

Comment: But when i give the data like below : padmini.chandrashekar@gmail.com
nishu.c@gmail.com
abhi.d@gmail.com
abhi.g@gmail.com , i am getting only the first value as output. can you pls check once

Comment: My MsgBox displays only the first cell's value if there is more than one cell in an area, compare `& " = " & rColored.Areas(i).Cells(1).Value`. The second cell would be `rColored.Areas(i).Cells(2).Value`. You can use `rColored.area(1).Cells.Count`

Comment: Hi I tried rColored.Areas(i).Cells.Count , but it gives me the count of colored cells not value. also i tried rColored.Areas(i).Cells(i).value , it is not giving all cell values. it gives the first and last

Comment: That's correct. But you can use the `Count` to build a loop in which you extract the value. In fact, `For Each Cell in rColored.Area(1).Cells: Debug.Print Cell.Value: Next Cell`, where `Cell` is a Range, should also work.

Comment: Thank you for your guidance , i used below code as you suggested and got the output .. ```For i = 1 To rColored.Areas.Count
        For Each Cell In rColored.Areas(i).Cells
        Txt = Cell.Value
        MsgBox Txt
        Next Cell
      Next i ```